# Jolt: modify-default-beta: what does the first argument do?

Tags: json, jolt

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411165/check-if-null-or-empty-in-jolt-and-put-another-value-which-is-present-in-input-j) regarding replacing a non-existing field with another field's value. It explains the usage of `modify-default-beta` operation. Example mentioned in the post:

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "shipping_address": {
        "address": "@(2,payment_address.address)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Input A, where there is not shipping address

```
{
  "payment_address": {
    "address": "some address"
  },
  "shipping_address": {}
}
```

Produces output A, where the billing address is copied over

```
{
  "payment_address" : {
    "address" : "some address"
  },
  "shipping_address" : {
    "address" : "some address"
  }
}
```

What is the meaning of the "2" in `@(2,payment_address.address)`. I tried this example [here](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception) and it works even if I replace the "2" with a "3".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jolt operations do a parallel tree walk of the input JSON and the Spec.   It starts at the root the Spec & input JSON and then does a depth first traversal.

While it is is doing it's depth first traversal it maintains a "stack" of the data / nodes that it has matched.

Thus in this spec, when you "match" down to "address"

```
"operation": "modify-default-beta",
"spec": {
  "shipping_address": {
    "address": "@(2,payment_address.address)"
  }
}
```

The stack looks like :

```
Stack "pointer"  Matched value       Pointer to Input
0                "address"           Value of Address : String if it exists
1                "shipping_address"  Value of "shipping_address" : Map if it exists
2                "_root_"            A made up entry to point to Input Json (Map or List)
3                "_root_"            Another "root" that points to a Map  
                                       WorkAround to deal with top level List JSON input
```

So the "2" gets you back up to the "top level" of the input Json, so that you can "navigate" down "payment_address.address".

"3" works because you are now in the wrapper that makes it so that all "top level" input to the Transforms is a Map, to workaround the fact that a top level list / "[]" if valid JSON.   This wrapper is special cased to have the same reference as the "2".

"4" does not not exist in the stack, and so it doesn't do anything.